# Isolated points in subsets of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

For a topological space $X$, is there an equivalent condition under which every subset of $X$ has finitely many isolated points?

Comment: If the space is infinite and satisfies this it can't be  Hausdorff.

Answer (score 5):

Every Noetherian space has this property, and the converse holds if you assume the space is $T_1$.

First, suppose some subset of $X$ has infinitely many isolated points.  Taking a countably infinite subset of those isolated points, we get a subspace $D=\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ which is discrete.  Now for each $m$, let $A_m=\overline{\{x_n:n\geq m\}}$.  Note that if $n<m$, then $x_n\not\in A_m$, since there is an open set containing $x_n$ and no other element of $D$.  It follows that the sets $A_m$ are all distinct, and form a strictly decreasing infinite sequence of closed subsets of $X$.  Thus $X$ is not Noetherian.

Conversely, suppose $X$ is $T_1$ and not Noetherian.  Let $A_1\supset A_2\supset\dots$ be a strictly decreasing infinite sequence of closed subsets of $X$.  For each $n$, choose a point $x_n\in A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$.  Then I claim the subset $D=\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ is discrete (and in particular has infinitely many isolated points).  Indeed, for each $n$, the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is open in $D$, being the intersection of $D$ with the open set $X\setminus A_{n+1}$.  Since $X$ is $T_1$, it follows that every singleton is open in $D$.

The $T_1$ hypothesis is necessary here.  For instance, let $X=\mathbb{N}$, topologized by saying $\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m\leq n\}$ is open for each $n$.  Then $X$ is not Noetherian, but no subset of $X$ has more than one isolated point.

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder what would happen if you wanted to avoid using axiom of choice. Probably a huge mess. ;)

Comment: The axiom of choice is not necessary for the first implication--instead of constructing the sequence $A_n$, you can just take an infinite discrete subset and consider the collection of all closures of cofinite subsets of it, which is a collection of closed subsets with no minimal element.  The use of choice in the second implication seems unavoidable though.

Comment: Nice dodge! I thought there is some trouble with DCC -- this is probably not equivalent to the minimal element condition, but the latter seems like the correct definition of Noetherianity in absence of axiom of choice. For the second part, you would probably have to account for the subtleties of infinity without choice: are we talking about Dedekind or Tarski infnite sets?